# @Singleton @Startup @PostConstruct method guaranteed to return before EJBs made available for client calls?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, startup, ejb-3.1

In the context of a `Java EE 6` application run on `WebSphere 8.0`, I need to execute a number of startup tasks before any business method can be executed. Using  a `@Startup`, `@Singleton` bean for this purpose seems like a promising solution. However, it is not entirely clear to me how exactly the application lifecycle would look like. The [EJB 3.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf) states the following:

> By default, the container is responsible for deciding when to
> initialize a Singleton bean instance. However, the bean developer can
> optionally configure the Singleton for eager initialization. If the
> Startup annotation appears on the Singleton bean class or if the
> Singleton has been designated via the deployment  descriptor  as
> requiring  eager  initialization, the  container  must  initialize
> the  Singleton  bean instance during the application startup sequence.
> The container must initialize all such startup-time Singletons before
> any client requests are delivered to any enterprise bean components in
> the application.

1. In the last sentence, what exactly constitutes *initialization*? Will the container wait for the `@PostConstruct` method of the `@Startup` bean to return before making enterprise beans available to client requests?
2. Speaking of *client requests*, do scheduled executions of an EJB method with the `@Scheduled` annotation count as one in this context?

I need to guarantee that some code is executed on application startup before any of the business methods in any of the application's various EJBs can be run, be it through client calls or scheduled executions. Does running the startup code inside the `@PostConstruct` method of a `@Singleton`, `@Startup` bean provide such a guarantee? If not, is there any other way to guarantee this behavior?

Comment: Well, it would certainly be bad design for an application server to serve beans that are still in the middle of running their `@PostConstruct` methods.

Comment: @Kayaman There is a difference between serving beans in the middle of their `@PostConstruct` methods and preventing calls to *all* beans while *any* `@Startup` bean is in its `@PostConstruct` method, which is the behavior required by the spec.

Comment: @BrettKail Indeed there is. The latter guaranteeing that the former can't happen. However since his quote didn't explicitly mention `@PostConstruct`, I believe he was wondering whether `@PostConstruct` is part of initialization or not.

Comment: @Kayaman The section in the spec that discusses singleton initialization specifically discusses `@PostConstruct` methods.

Comment: @BrettKail But Lord Zuthulu (if that is his real name) didn't quote that part. I'm not confused here, I didn't post this question.

Comment: @Kayaman I probably could have worded the question better. Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, the container waits for the `@PostConstruct` method of all `@Startup` beans in the module ("EJB application") to return before allowing any client requests.
2. Yes, this is the case in WebSphere Application Server as implied by the [Developing singleton session beans](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_ssb.html) topic in the Knowledge Center, which says "A PostConstruct method in a singleton bean can create an EJB timer [...] However, to avoid a deadlock, the PostConstruct method must not wait for an EJB timer to run".  In other words, timer callback invocations will wait for `@PostConstruct` methods to complete, so `@PostConstruct` methods must not wait for timer callback invocations to complete.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894071/can-a-long-running-startup-singleton-session-bean-delay-a-j2ee-container-initial). Could you take a look?